# C++ using a pointer to point another pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am studying C++ from Herbert Schildt's book "Teach Yourself C++ 3rd Edition". In one example code, something made me so confused.

```
#include <iostream>
using namesapce std;

template <class data_t> class list {
    data_t data;
    list *next;

    public:
        list(data_t d);
        void add(list *node) {node->next = this; next = 0; }
        list *getnext() { return next;}
        data_t getdata() { return data;}
};
```

I didn't write all code in example, I only writed class declaration.
In here, I didn't understand one part. First, the "*node" pointer which belongs to "add" function, is using as "node->next" for "*next" pointer. I didn't understand the aim in here, why we don't directly use like {"next=this; next=0;} ? Also, how can we use an empty pointer (*node) to point another empty pointer (*next) ? I am missing maybe some key concepts, thanks for helps.

Comment: Here is a nice list of [C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). I would skip a book that preaches that struct wiring so popular with universities. Use STL containers instead.

Comment: You've got a pointer to a `list`, which contains a pointer to another `list`, which contains a pointer to another `list`... this is the normal way of linked-lists. But you'll be much happier using `std::list` from the standard library than using this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function `add()`:

```
template<typename data_t>
class list {
    // ...
    void add(list *node) {node->next = this; next = 0; }
    // ...
};
```

The point of the function is to add `this` to the list, as the next element after `node`.  Think about it like a train: `add()` tells the current car to hook itself onto the back of another car, with the function's parameter telling it which car to link to.
Note that this function expects `node` to *not* be a null pointer; if it is null, you'll probably get a segmentation fault.

```
void add(list* node) {
    node->next = this; // Tells "node" to register the current node as its "next" node.
                       // Should first check whether "node" is a valid pointer.
    next = 0;          // Tells the current node to register a null pointer as its "next" node,
                       //  signifying that it's currently the last node in the list.
                       // Note that instead of assigning 0, it should instead assign either
                       //  "nullptr" (C++11 or later) or "NULL" (pre-C++11).
}
```

Therefore, when used like this:

```
list<int> start(42), second(24);
second.add(&start);
```

It will do the following:

```
(&start)->next = &second;
(&second)->next = 0;
```

This creates a singly linked list, which looks like this:

```
Start: "start"
  --> Next: "second"
    --> Next: None.
```

Or, more concisely:

```
start->second->NULL
```

---

Remember, when inside a non-static member function, any member variable accesses are assumed to operate on `this` unless otherwise specified.

```
template<typename data_t>
void list<data_t>::add(list* node) {
    node->next = this; // Operates on node, not on this.
    next = 0;          // Operates on this; becomes "this->next = 0;"
}
```

If this function intstead was just `{next = this; next = 0;}`, then it would be:

```
template<typename data_t>
void list<data_t>::add(list *node) {
    this->next = this; // Bad.  Creates a circular linked list, where "this" is ALWAYS the
                       //  next node after "this".
    this->next = 0;    // Renders the above line entirely pointless, by indicating that there
                       //  are no nodes after "this".
}
```